# lapply a function with changing argument value for each element of list

Tags: r, list, lapply, mapply

I have a list of data frames

```
listofdf <-  list(a = a, b = b, c = c)
```

I have a function:

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, ll, ul) {
  require(dplyr)
  x <- x %>% filter(SALES < quantile(SALES, probs = c(ll)) & SALES > quantile(SALES, probs = c(ul)))
  return(x)
}
```

I want to apply this function on the list. **The condition is that the value of arguments `ul` and `ll` in the function change for each element of the list.**

**I cannot write:** `lapply(listofdf, remove_outliers, 0.01, 0.99)` because 0.01 & 0.99 change depending on the df.

I have an inkling that this can be solved using `Map` or `mapply` so I tried this:

`listofdf <- Map(remove_outliers, listofdf, MoreArgs = list(ll = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), ul = c(0.90, 0.95, 0.99)))`

but i got errors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In filter_impl(.data, dots) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In filter_impl(.data, dots) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In filter_impl(.data, dots) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In filter_impl(.data, dots) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Don't use `MoreArgs` in `Map`. Just try `Map(remove_outliers, listofdf, c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), c(0.90, 0.95, 0.99))`

Comment: returns an empty list ! **scratches head**

Comment: after 2 hours of struggling, I realize that I was reversing the values of arguments in the function when I was using Map which was resulting in a NULL data set. In short I was writing: `Map(remove_outliers, listofdf, c(0.9, 0.95, 0.98), c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))` and obviously no row in my data met this condition !

Answer (score 1):

Here, I've tried it with a dummy removeOutlier function

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, ll, ul) {
return(x>ll & x< ul)
}
listofdf <-  list(a = 1:10, b = 100:120, c = 1000:1010)

filt<- mapply( FUN=remove_outliers, listofdf , 
    ll=c(2,102,1004), ul=c(8,117,1008)  )

res<- mapply(FUN="[", listofdf,filt)
res
```

Comment: thanks for trying. I had the answer all along and was just misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with the way you are passing arguments. Simply Try:

```
    mapply(remove_outilers, l, ll = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), ul = c(0.90, 0.95, 0.99))
```

Comment: What is the second argument in your function "l" ? Stands for name of the list? I tried it exactly in this format: `mapply(remove_outliers, listofdf, ll= c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03), ul = c(0.95, 0.98, 0.99))` - returns an empty list !

Comment: thanks for trying. I had the answer all along and was just misinterpreting the results.

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind into a single dataframe?

```
big_data =
  listofdf %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "source")
```